# BufferedImage wrong buffer size

Tags: java, c++, image, java-native-interface, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting image data from c++, and I want to pass it to Java using JNI.
My code is as follows:

```
jclass bitmap_class = (jclass) env->FindClass("java/awt/image/BufferedImage");
jclass raster_class = (jclass) env->FindClass("java/awt/image/WritableRaster");
jclass data_class = (jclass) env->FindClass("java/awt/image/DataBufferByte");
jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(bitmap_class, "<init>", "(III)V");

int w = nativeFrame->Width();
int h = nativeFrame->Height();
int t = 2; // That is TYPE_INT_ARGB
jobject bitmap = env->NewObject(bitmap_class, constructor, w, h, t);//byteType);

jmethodID getRaster = env->GetMethodID(bitmap_class, "getRaster", "()Ljava/awt/image/WritableRaster;");
jobject raster = env->CallObjectMethod(bitmap, getRaster);

 jmethodID getDataBuffer = env->GetMethodID(raster_class, "getDataBuffer", "()Ljava/awt/image/DataBuffer;");
 jobject dataBuffer = env->CallObjectMethod(raster, getDataBuffer);

 jmethodID getData = env->GetMethodID(data_class, "getData", "()[B");
 jobject pixelsObject = env->CallObjectMethod(dataBuffer, getData);

 jbyteArray pixels = (jbyteArray)pixelsObject;
 long sz = env->GetArrayLength(pixels);

 env->SetByteArrayRegion(pixels, (jsize)0, (jsize)nativeFrame->BufferSize(),  (jbyte*) nativeFrame->GetData());
```

As I am creating `BufferedImage` of the same size and color format as a c++ image, I would expect it to have a buffer of the same size.

However, after getting **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** I started to investigate and found that the size of the `BufferedImage`'s buffer (the **pixels** variable in my code) is ***4 times less*** then needed. One may say that `GetArrayLength` returns a number of elements, not bytes, but as I am using `jbytearray`, it should be the same as a number of bytes. Anyway I shouldn't get an exception. But I do.

**Example**

For 100x100 32bpp image, my c++ image buffer is of the correct 100*100*4=40000 size, but when I call

```
new BufferedImage(100,100, TYPE_INT_ARGB)
```

I get buffer size (**sz** in my code) equals to 10000.

Why is that? What  (probably obvious) am I missing?

Comment: yes, I am on 32 bit Linux platform

Comment: Besides, it is Java, so it is always 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved, when I used another color type, **`TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR`** instead of **`TYPE_INT_ARGB`**. I cannot see how it may affect a buffer size, as both are, according to documentation:

```
an image with 8-bit RGBA color components
```

However I am getting a correct buffer size now.
I will try to investigate more and will post an update when I have found an explanation.